# How to add variable that changes depending on userinput to sortedlist C#?

Tags: c#, generics, collections, sortedlist

The headline doesn't really fit but I'm not good at explaining in just one headline. Here goes: I want to put a double variable that changes depending on userinput into a Sortedlist and then loop through it so that it the output would be something like this:
Distance: 1
Distance : 2 
Distance : 3 
I can't use an arraylist because I don't know how many double values I will get.

Comment: An arraylist won´t force you to know its size. Anyway you should use a `List<T>` instead which is strongly typed instead of `ArrayList` or `SortedList`.

Comment: Even when using something like myList.Add(variablehere) and loop through it with a foreach loop I will still only get the latest value that got assigned to the variable wouldn't I ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you are asking for, so a wrote a code that will be "useful" for two scenarios: First, you want to access the last value that the user wrote. Second, you want to access all values on the list. And third, you want all of that on a single variable.

```
public class DistanceList : List<double>
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        int count = 1;
        string resultString = String.Empty;
        foreach (var item in this)
        {
            resultString = String.Concat(resultString, "Distance ", count.ToString(), ": ", item.ToString(), ";");
            count = +1;
        }
        return resultString;
    }

    public static implicit operator double(DistanceList list)
    {
        return list.Single();
    }
}
```

This class overrides the ToString method, and loops through all the values and add them on a string, giving the output you stated on your question "the output would be something like this: Distance: 1 Distance : 2 Distance : 3".

If you want the last value there is a implicit conversion for double which return the only value for the list, for one value will work just like a regular variable, for more than one value if you try to use as a double it will just trow an exception.

Just be aware that you will not be able to write directly to this variable and expect to add the item on the list, you will still need to use the `List<T>().Add` method.

But I really hope that it is not what you are asking for, because this kind of design will cause you a lot of trouble down the road.

Will you always be checking whether there is just one item so you can treat it as a double, or need to deal with many values? You will probably forget doing so somewhere...

This class only transforms them on a string, what if you need them as doubles to sum them up or something? You might end up parsing that string back into a `List<double>`...